# WP-admin giving 404

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

When I go to /wp-admin/ I get a 404 not found error. This just started tonight. I don't have any plugins that change the login or the wp-admin page. my site is https://sturtz.ml/
This is all the log says.

`[27-Apr-2020 12:34:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:34:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:34:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:34:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:35:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:35:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104
[27-Apr-2020 12:35:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/main/wp-config.php on line 104`

Comment: Can someone please help me, I need to get into my wp-admin

Comment: I suggest you rename plugins folder and create an empty plugin folder. Your site takes long but still cannot load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you rename the original plugin folder and create a blank plugin then it works. If in case log file is not immediately reflecting the error or it is not obvious for identifying the error. Moving the disabled plugin one by one to the new empty plugin folder is another way to find out which plugin(s) cause the issue.

One or more of the plugins generate php error which I believe. 
I suggest you turn on the debug with output file to trace.
You may do the following steps to debug.

1. Update your wp-config.php by adding the following statement

```
// turn on debug mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// the path to file, WP_DEBUG must be TRUE to use
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', 'path_to_log/debug.log' );
```

2. rename back the plugin folder
3. run the site once
4. go to see the debug.log to find out the error portion

If you haven't done anything, most likely, your host update PHP version I guess.
There are many factors, just see the debug log to find out.

For more about debug, you may visit [Debug WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Nothing appears in the log file

Comment: Ok, if so, you may try the following, you use the empty plugin folder, move plugin one by one from original. See which one cause problem. This could also help to sort out.

Comment: I got the log working,

Comment: Glad it works, I just found that I have a typo, thanks for your time and test.

Comment: Thank you again.